# Algorithm - Find the the number of rectangles covering a given rectangle area

Tags: algorithm

This is not a homework problem . Its an interview question . I am not able to come up with good solution for this problem .

Problem :

Given an n*n (bottom left(0,0) , top right(n,n)) grid and n rectangles with sides parallel to the coordinate axis. The bottom left and top right coordinates for the n rectangles are provided in the form (x1,y1)(x1',y1') .... (xn,yn)(xn',yn'). There are M queries which asks for the number of rectangles that cover a rectangle with coordinates (a,b)(c,d).  How do I solve it in an efficient way ? Is there a way to precompute for all coordinate positions so that I can return the answer in O(1) .

Constraints:
1<= n <= 1000

Comment: There is a lot left to clarify. What are you searching for? (you didn't say in the question!!) What on earth does "M queries" mean? What happens if I specify a region that covers only part of a rectangle? Lots of questions that need to be asked first.

Comment: The fact that you ask for a O(1) solution makes me confused about the n rectangles. If you have to use all n rectangles to calculate your solution, that makes it an O(n) solution at best.

Comment: -1 for not providing details. I suspect that your problem was that you had a poor grasp of the question, in which case the answer is irrelevant--you can never come up with a correct answer without a correct understanding of what the interviewer was asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to create, in O(n^4) space and O(n^5) time, a data structure that provides O(1) lookups.  If M  exceeds O(n^2) it might be worthwhile to do so. It also is straightforward to create, in O(n^2) space and O(n^3) time, a data structure that provides lookups in O(n) time.  If M is  O(n^2), that may be a better tradeoff; ie, take  O(n^3) precomputation time and  O(n^3) time for O(n^2) lookups at O(n) each.

For the  precomputation, make an n by n array of lists.  Let L_pq denote the list for cell p,q of the n by n grid.  Each list contains up to n rectangles, with lists all ordered by the same relation (ie if `Ri < Rj` in one list, `Ri < Rj` in every list that pair is in).  The set of lists takes time O(n^3) to compute, taken either as "for each C of n^2 cells, for each R of n rectangles, if C in R add R to L_C" or as "for each R of n rectangles, for each cell C in R, add R to L_C".

Given a query (a,b,c,d), in time O(n) count the size of the intersection of lists L_ab and L_cd.  For O(1) lookups, first do the precomputation mentioned above, and then for each a,b, for each `c>a` and `d<b`, do the O(n) query mentioned above and save the result in P[a,b,c,d] where P is an appropriately large array of integers.

It is likely that an O(n^3) or perhaps O(n^2 · log n) precomputation method exists using either [segment trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), [range trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), or [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Higher_Dimensions) that can do queries in O(log n) time.